# how to replace part of object in Terraform

Tags: function, object, terraform

I'm constructing some objects to store the required information in Terraform
I just defined a variable and its value as below

```
vnetsettings = {
  HUBVNET  = {
      VNET_Name = "co-vnet-01"
      VNET_Location = "eastasia"
      VNET_Resource_Group = "CoreInfra"
      VNET_Address_Space = ["10.1.0.0/16","10.2.0.0/16"]
      VNET_Tags = {
          env = "prod"
          application = "hub"
      }
      VNET_DNS_Servers = ["10.1.0.4","10.2.0.4"]
  }

  MGMTVNET  = {
      VNET_Name = "mgmt-vnet-01"
      VNET_Location = "eastasia"
      VNET_Resource_Group = "MGMT"
      VNET_Address_Space = ["10.3.0.0/16","10.4.0.0/16"]
      VNET_Tags = {
          env = "prod"
          application = "MGMT"
      }
      VNET_DNS_Servers = ["10.1.0.4","10.2.0.4"]
  }
}
```

my question is how can i bulk replace some of the attributes in the object, like VNET_Resource_Group

below is the result i want, everything same as the one above, except for the VNET_Resource_Group

```
vnetsettings = {
  HUBVNET  = {
      VNET_Name = "co-vnet-01"
      VNET_Location = "eastasia"
      VNET_Resource_Group = "replacedvalue"
      VNET_Address_Space = ["10.1.0.0/16","10.2.0.0/16"]
      VNET_Tags = {
          env = "prod"
          application = "hub"
      }
      VNET_DNS_Servers = ["10.1.0.4","10.2.0.4"]
  }

  MGMTVNET  = {
      VNET_Name = "mgmt-vnet-01"
      VNET_Location = "eastasia"
      VNET_Resource_Group = "replacedvalue"
      VNET_Address_Space = ["10.3.0.0/16","10.4.0.0/16"]
      VNET_Tags = {
          env = "prod"
          application = "MGMT"
      }
      VNET_DNS_Servers = ["10.1.0.4","10.2.0.4"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create a `local` variable which is essentially a copy of the original object. Also, while making the copy you can replace an attribute from the original objects using the [`merge`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/merge) function.

```sh
locals {
  vnetsettings_updated = {
    for key, value in var.vnetsettings : key => merge(value, { VNET_Resource_Group = "replacedvalue" })
  }
}

# Example usage of the updated object
output "vnetsettings" {
  description = "VNET settings with updated VNET_Resource_Group"
  value       = local.vnetsettings_updated 
}
```